# Write alert policies list in Cloud Storage with cloud functions

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

I want to write a list of alert policies in a json file in cloud storage. I have the script below:

```
def my_function(request):
    alert_client = monitoring_v3.AlertPolicyServiceClient()
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    project_name = 'projects/my_project'
    bucket_name = 'test'

    policies = alert_client.list_alert_policies(name=project_name)
    for policy in policies:
        print(policy)
        destination_blob_name = 'test'
        bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
        blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
        blob.upload_from_string("{}".format(json.dumps(policy)))
```

This script is not working and returns me the following error: `TypeError: Object of type AlertPolicy is not JSON serializable"`

Now a couple of things:

- Using the API explorer or looking at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.alertPolicies/list?apix_params=%7B%22name%22%3A%22projects%2Fgtm-monitoring-poc%22%7D) the response from the list method should be easy to handle. However I'm writing my cloud functions in Python and It seems that the response is different.
- I understand that there is something around the way pagination is handle but I don't understand how to deal with it.
- I can `print(policies)` but the log output is kind of weird with a line for each element of the json object. Why is that? What does it mean?
- How can I handle this response? Is there a generic approach here or is this specific to the API?
- Still I'm able to access each variable independently `policy.name`, `policy.conditions` etc... does it means that I have to rebuild the json object I want manually?

Comment: what happens if you convert the policy to a string, using fe: `blob.upload_from_string("{}".format(json.dumps(str(policy))))`

Comment: Well it works technically but the output is very messy and will be difficult to work with.

Answer (score 0):

According to the googleapis [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/monitoring/latest/monitoring_v3/alert_policy_service.html) of the alert policy service, iterating over the list of alert policies using `list_alert_policies()` automatically resolves subsequent pages of the response. You should not worry about implementing pagination logic according to the documentation:

> Returns: The protocol for the ListAlertPolicies response. Iterating over this object will yield results and resolve additional pages automatically. [source](https://googleapis.dev/python/monitoring/latest/monitoring_v3/alert_policy_service.html)

As for the [type](https://googleapis.dev/python/monitoring/latest/monitoring_v3/types.html#google.cloud.monitoring_v3.types.AlertPolicy) `AlertPolicy`, it does not appear to natively be able to convert to JSON. You might have to build the JSON objects by calling on the respective properties of the `AlertPolicy` objects that are returned, or you can also implement something similar to this `ProtoEncoder` [class](https://github.com/googleapis/python-monitoring/blob/77980ff1b910b89ca4177cc193f7d3033ca7d871/samples/snippets/v3/alerts-client/snippets.py#L154) which appears to return JSON from `AlertPolicy` types. As for the available properties on the `AlertPolicy` objects, [here is the source](https://googleapis.dev/python/monitoring/latest/_modules/google/cloud/monitoring_v3/types/alert.html#AlertPolicy).

```
class ProtoEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    """Encode protobufs as json."""

    def default(self, obj):
        if type(obj) in (monitoring_v3.AlertPolicy, monitoring_v3.NotificationChannel):
        text = proto.Message.to_json(obj)
        return json.loads(text)
    return super(ProtoEncoder, self).default(obj)
```